# Is it possible to train model 4 features but predict using 1 feature?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, prediction

I need to predict bug count for 3 months. This depends on 4 inputs, but in UI the user will only input 1 feature and model needs to predict the bug count.

Is it possible?

Below is a sample dataset.

| Month | Year | Dependency | Activity | Size | BugCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2019 | XXX | Full Assessment | Small | 105 |
| 4 | 2019 | XXX | Full Assessment | Small | 14 |
| 1 | 2019 | YYY | Full Assessment | Small | 1 |
| 4 | 2019 | ZZZ | Full Assessment | Medium | 1 |
| 2 | 2020 | AAA | Full Assessment | Large | 314 |

Comment: No, unless the model can get the remaining 3 features elsewhere.

Comment: 2 of the 3 features have only 2 & 3 labels resp. Is it possible to keep them constant and build a model? And iterate through it to get the predictions?

Comment: If the remaining features are constant, why not just train a model without them?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was able to do this defining a dataframe with all combinations of Activity & Size and calling the particular dependency whenever a request was sent for that particular dependency. Once I got a list of predictions, I added it up & shared it as response.